# Parsing a log file for a specific string

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a log file for a specific string however, the log file has similar strings and when I use my for loop to search the file, it is grabbing the most recent sequence of those characters. Any ideas?

```
    search1 = xyz
    search2 = xy

    while file as f:
         for line in file:
             if search2 in line:
                 print(line)
```

the log file looks similar to this

asd 
asda
asdaga
asdga 
xy
xyz   <---
The results I am receiving is the xyz line printing, even though my search variable was xy. I am guessing this is happening because the sequence 'xy' is in 'xyz' but can I search for the exact sequence of a string?

Thanks,

Comment: if you're writing the log file yourself, a simple fix would be to use markers that aren't substrings of each other. or you could add punctuation like Err_xy_ vs Err_xyz_

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick would be to `split()` the `line`, (optionally make it a set), and then do the membership test:

```
for line in file:
    # If you want to do many tests, then 
    # creating a `set` might be a good idea
    # line = set(line.split())
    # if search2 in line:
    # ...
    if search2 in line.split():
        print(line)
```

Comment: @Aiven Yes, thats why it is mentioned as optional.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file such as this:

```
blah xy blah
xxyz 123
adfayx
dat xyz data
```

Then the following Python code uses `regex` to find `xy`:

```
import re

with open('file', 'r') as f:
    file_contents = f.read()


re_target = re.compile('\sxy\s')
results = re_target.findall(file_contents)
print results
```

All this does is look for the string `xy` with whitespace on either side of it. Let me know if you have any questions!